# Return data from http inside function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, angular-promise

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32417640/angular-return-id-from-http-inside-parent-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) reference, to return data from an http-request inside a function:

```
function getdetails(id) {

            var datafordetails = {
                data1: {
                    item1: "",
                    item2: ""
                },
                data2: {
                    item3: "",
                    ID: id
                }
            };

            var jsonDataDetails = JSON.stringify(datafordetails);
            return $http({
                url: "http://...",
                method: "POST",
                data: jsonDataDetails,
                dataType: "json",
                timeout: 5000,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            })
                .then(function (res) {
                    var data = res.data;
                    responsedata=data.d;
                    return responsedata;

                },function (error) {
                    $scope.status = status;
                    console.log("Unable to update. No internet?");
                })
        }
```

My goal is that `var testing = getdetails('12345');` gives me the responsedata for that ID, but I'm getting back `Promise {$$state: Object...`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output you are getting is nothing but a promise object which has been returned by the `$http.get` method. Basically you need to put `.then` function over `getdetails2` function for getting data from the promise object when it `resolve`/`reject`.

**Code**

```
getdetails2('12345').then(function(data){ //success callback
   //you will get data here in data parameter of function,
   var testing = data;
}, function(error){ //error callback
   console.log(error)
})
```